# How to restrict changes to jQuery variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table and each tr element alternates between a white and gray background. When the user hovers over a tr element, the background changes to green. When the user clicks on a tr element, a hidden tr element that is below the clicked on tr element appears. At that time, the tr element the user click on and the hidden on that appear have their backgrounds set to blue. When the user clicks the tr element again, the tr element below once again is hidden. At that point, the background color should go back to it's default color of white or gray. Instead, it stays the blue color.

I know why it's happening, I am just not sure how to fix it in jQuery. Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="retail-listing">
<div class="container">
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Sales Price</th>
        <th>Odometer</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Series</th>
        <th>Body</th>
        <th>Drive Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="retail-list-top">
        <td>09/09/2013</td>
        <td>$25,200</td>
        <td>8,231</td>
        <td>2011</td>
        <td>Pick-up</td>
        <td>Quad Cab</td>
        <td>4WD</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr class="retail-list-detail">
        <td>Vin#: 107RV1GP8BS000000</td>
        <td>Make: Dodge Truck</td>
        <td>Model: Ram 1500</td>
        <td>Sale Type: Dealer</td>
        <td>Region: New England</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr class="retail-list-top">
        <td>09/09/2013</td>
        <td>$25,200</td>
        <td>8,231</td>
        <td>2011</td>
        <td>Pick-up</td>
        <td>Quad Cab</td>
        <td>4WD</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr class="retail-list-detail">
        <td>Vin#: 107RV1GP8BS000000</td>
        <td>Make: Dodge Truck</td>
        <td>Model: Ram 1500</td>
        <td>Sale Type: Dealer</td>
        <td>Region: New England</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
    <table>
      <tr class="retail-list-top">
        <td>09/09/2013</td>
        <td>$25,200</td>
        <td>8,231</td>
        <td>2011</td>
        <td>Pick-up</td>
        <td>Quad Cab</td>
        <td>4WD</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr class="retail-list-detail">
        <td>Vin#: 107RV1GP8BS000000</td>
        <td>Make: Dodge Truck</td>
        <td>Model: Ram 1500</td>
        <td>Sale Type: Dealer</td>
        <td>Region: New England</td>
      </tr>
    </table>  
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(function() {

    var bgColor = $('.retail-list-top').css('background-color');

    $('.retail-list-detail').hide();

    $('.retail-list-top').hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#c9e9a4");
    },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", bgColor);
        }
    );

    $('.retail-list-top').bind('click', function() {

        $(this).toggleClass('detail-slide');

        if ($(this).hasClass('detail-slide')) {
            $(this).closest('table').next().find('.retail-list-detail').show();
            $(this).css({backgroundColor :"#e1eff4", border : "none"});
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#e1eff4");
            },
                function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#e1eff4");
                }
            );
        } else {
            $(this).closest('table').next().find('.retail-list-detail').hide();
            $(this).css({backgroundColor : bgColor, borderBottom : "1px solid #c4c4c4"});
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why are you binding hover event inside click handler? You have already bound the hover event. BTW, the second hover method just set same color in in/out handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend simplifying this greatly through the use of CSS. I've done so, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xjMqj/).

I also made use of adding and removing a class, blue, to give the "opened" table row a blue background. This way, it is not an inline style when clicked, but just in a class.

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $('.retail-list-top').click( function() {

        $(this).toggleClass('detail-slide');

        if ($(this).hasClass('detail-slide')) {
            $(this).closest('table').next().find('.retail-list-detail').show();
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('table').next().find('.retail-list-detail').hide();
            $(this).removeClass('blue');
        }
    })
});
```

**CSS**

```
.retail-list-top:hover{
    background:#c9e9a4;
}

.retail-list-detail{
    display:none;
}

.blue{
    background:#e1eff4;
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. I got everything fixed by going off of your code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. Is that what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/55chh/1/

**JS**

```
$(function() {

var bgColor = $('.retail-list-top').css('background-color');

$('.retail-list-top').bind('click', function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('detail-slide');

    if ($(this).hasClass('detail-slide')) {
        $(this).closest('table').next().find('.retail-list-detail').show();
        $(this).css({background:"#e1eff4", border : "none"});
        $(this).removeClass("retail-list-hover");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('table').next().find('.retail-list-detail').hide();
        $(this).css({backgroundColor : bgColor, borderBottom : "1px solid #c4c4c4"});
        $(this).addClass("retail-list-hover");
    }
})
});
```

**CSS**

```
.retail-list-hover:hover {
    background: #c9e9a4;
}

.retail-list-detail {
    display: none;
}
```